# Extracting third axes, data cube pyfits

Tags: python, astronomy, data-cube, fits

I have a data cube fitsfile, consisting of an intensity at a regular (512x512) 2d grid. There is also a third axes however; each value on this axis corresponds to a frequency. At each frequency, a such 2d picture is taken.

I have been trying to find these frequency values within the fits file, but I have had no luck so far. I know there are 140 different frequency channels, I know the units etc. by looking at the header of the fits file. *The problem is finding the values of those 140 channels.*

Programming in PYTHON by the way.

Comment: I found it! Problem solved, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

It is usually given in the same manner that coordinates are given for axis "n". A reference value "CRVALn", a reference position "CRPIXn", the increment for each pixel/channel "CDELTn" and the type of coordinates given in those keywords "CTYPEn". So from that you can just work out the values of each "channel" in your cube as

```
(channel_number - CRPIXn) * CRDELTn + CRVALn
```

Since you said you solved it, perhaps you could post your solution for the benefit of others?

---

Edit/Addition :

More information about how this is expressed in FITS files :
http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_wcs.html

especially the paper "Representations of spectral coordinates in FITS" Greisen et al. (2005) ([link](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-bib_query?bibcode=2006A%26A...446..747G&db_key=AST&data_type=HTML&format=&high=42261c2ea130558) to paper on NASA ADS)